# Getting TreeViewItem from an another Itemtype

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

I'm in trouble, and I search and search but can find no solution. Now I want to present this problem here. I have a simple Treeview whose elements are bound to a property in the ViewModel:

```
<!-- my XAML-Code -->
ItemsSource="{Binding RessourcesTree}"

// my ViewModel
IList <RessourceTreeViewItem> RessourcesTree
```

My problem is, that I dont know how I can get from an element of type RessourceTreeViewItem, the "owner"-element of type TreeViewItem. Is there a way to get the items of my RessourcesTree as each real item of type TreeViewItem?

Answer (score 0):

RessourceTreeViewItem is your own type which is probably why you are not getting results - try searching for TreeViewItem for some examples on the web.

Assuming RessourceTreeViewItem is an override of TreeViewItem (you haven't provided enough information to be sure of this but i'm assuming so from the naming) you can get to its items using the property

```
RessourcesTree.Items
```

so you could do this to get each as a TreeViewItem

```
foreach(var item in RessourcesTree.Items)
{
    var treeItem = (TreeViewItem)item;
    //do something with TreeViewItem

    //remember a TreeView is recursive.....
}
```

Comment: My class RessourceTreeViewItem inherits from these class: public abstract class PropertyChangedBase : INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyPropertyChanging. So I can´t cast the item directly to TreeViewItem. This would be fine, but it isn´t. Thank you!

Comment: Does it have a property of type TreeViewItem? if not then what you are asking is of course impossible. I would look into using the existing WPF TreeViewItem, and extending it for your needs if required..

Comment: Yes, I have a property of type TreeViewItem. In my XAML I have a <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle> with Setter and Property="behaviours:TreeViewBehaviour.Transmitter" Value="{Binding}". When an item is loaded, TransmitterChanged is fired and so I have an TreeViewItem. But when the RessourceItem is added, and the TreeViewItem is not expanded, it will not be loaded. So TransmitterChanged is not fired and I have not the TreeViewItem. Therefore I was looking for an alternating way.